# How do I invalidate an object in the Varnish cache when it has zero length?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to work around a backend server that will from time to time start serving up blank pages with a 200 OK response, by having Varnish continue to serve old cached versions of these pages (aka. grace mode).

First I tried inspecting the response in `vcl_fetch`, but as far as I have been able to figure out, there is no way to figure out the content length in `vcl_fetch`. Then I attempted to do the work in `vcl_deliver` (where the Content-Length header is available). That does work, but I can't figure out how to expunge the bad cached object (the one with the blank page), so that seems to be a no-go.

I was advised to set obj.grace and obj.ttl in `vcl_deliver`, and this is my current code:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  # If the front page is blank, invalidate this cached object, in hope
  # that we'll get a new one.
  if (req.url == "/" && std.integer(resp.http.content-length, 0) < 1000) {
    set obj.grace = 0m;
    set obj.ttl = 0m;

    return(restart);
  }
}
```

However, Varnish doesn't like that, and gives me this error when I try to load the VCL:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
'obj.grace': cannot be set in method 'vcl_deliver'.
At: ('input' Line 146 Pos 9)
    set obj.grace = 0m;
--------#########------
```

I get the same error for `obj.ttl` if I remove the `obj.grace` line – neither seems to be writable in `vcl_deliver`, even though [the docs say otherwise](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#variables). This is on Varnish 3.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

What i did is check the Content-Length for 0 and 20 in sub_vcl_fech and restart when this happens

```
if (beresp.http.Content-Length == "0" || beresp.http.Content-Length == "20"){
    return(restart);
}
```

*content length of 20 is what my server returned when an error occurs.*

in the sub vcl_recv i added a check on amount of restarts maximum of 2

```
if(req.restarts == 2){
   error 500 req.http.host;
}
```

**Option 2**

another option i got from the varnish documentation.
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html

1. Throw error in the vcl_fetch like: *error 751 req.http.host;*
2. add magic marker in the vcl_error.
3. add return(restart); in the vcl_error
4. check for magic marker set in vcl_recv or vcl_fetch

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in vcl_deliver is too late. This sub is called right before sending content to the client and obj should not be available anymore (only 'resp' which doesn't contain any ttl or grace parameter).

Did you try doing this in vcl_fetch ? You won't need to call 'restart' but directly 'hit_for_pass'.

Anyway, (not sure about that) I don't think grace mode can be used depending on response content since it's supposed to be triggered when you can't get any content update (backend failure). Maybe it could work by changing backend to a "zombie" one and restarting request but for sure, once you're in vcl_fetch, a response is...fetched, and grace mode won't trigger.

Comment: The problem is that I can't figure out a way to figure out if we got an empty response in `vcl_fetch`.

Comment: You can. Just check "beresp.http.content-length" instead of "resp" so you check content received from backend instead of content that'll be sent to client.

Comment: I think you're suggesting something like:

    if(!beresp.http.content-length) {
      set obj.grace = 5m;
    }

but that's still failing for me.

Comment: `if(!beresp.http.content-length)` checks header presence, not its value. You should rather use `if(beresp.http.content-length != "0")` (you can't use `> 0` since the header is provided as string).